# ECW Support removed QGIS - Can't reinstall QGIS on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, ecw

I had QGIS 3.10 installed on Ubuntu 18.04.  Hoping for ECW support I ran the bash code located

[here](https://gist.github.com/1papaya/568c4580b1909071696c1cb119101823).  While this code executed without error QGIS 3.10 is not available on my computer anymore.

After running the installation again using

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python3-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

I get the following error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-qgis : Depends: python3-qgis-common (= 1:3.4.15+28bionic-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
 qgis : Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.4.15+28bionic-ubuntugis) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qgis-common (= 1:3.4.15+28bionic-ubuntugis) but 1:3.10.2+28bionic-ubuntugis is to be installed
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-plugin-grass-common (= 1:3.4.15+28bionic-ubuntugis) but 1:3.10.2+28bionic-ubuntugis is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

How do I install QGIS given this situation?

Comment: You have to fix broken packages. You can search how do that in https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/ or whatever similar post.

Comment: Thanks @xunilk,  running sudo apt update --fix-missing reinstalled the missing dependencies.  If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as answered.

Comment: You're welcome. I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before running the installation of QGIS 3 again, you have to fix broken packages. You can search how do that in [maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/) or whatever similar post.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309161/dpkg-error-processing-package-qgis-providers-configure):

To fix this on my side, I had to uninstall libproj* manually

`sudo apt remove libproj15 libproj-dev libproj19`